# unable to clear the setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

Can someone help me to clear the SetInterval in below code. I already tired window.clearInterval(intervalListener) its not working.

```
    <audio id="audio1" controls="controls" ontimeupdate="init(this.currentTime)"; style="display:block;">
    <source src="Audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="Audio.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <embed height="50" width="100" src="Audio.mp3"></embed>
    </audio>

    function init(val)
    {
    var audio=document.getElementById('audio1');

    if(val==2)
    {
    var a=0;
    intervalListener = self.setInterval(function()

    {
        alert(a);
        if(a===8)
        {
          window.clearInterval(intervalListener);
        }
        a++;
    }, 1000);



    }

    }
```

Comment: Chech here http://jsfiddle.net/7XrUq/

Comment: i know it works well when called seperately.

Comment: i need it to be done on ontimeupdate on playing an audio

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. make sure that in `self.setInterval` self is actually the window.
2. `alert(a)` may be bugging the interval as it stops JS execution, try `console.log(a)` instead.

---

Also, `setInterval` is often better replaced by `setTimeout`

```
function interval(a){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(a);
        if(a<8) interval(++a);
    },1000);
}
interval(0);
```

Or, if you prefer without the anonymous function, you can use:

```
var a = 0;
function interval2(){
    console.log(a);
    if(a<8){
        a++;
        setTimeout(interval2,1000);
    }   
}
interval2();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare intervalListener outside the function :

```
var intervalListener;

function init(val) {
    var audio=document.getElementById('audio1');

    if(val==2) {
        var a=0;
        intervalListener = self.setInterval(function(){
            alert(a);
            if(a===8){
                window.clearInterval(intervalListener);
            }
            a++;
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare both `a` and `intervalListener` outside of all functions so that they are in a global scope.